# How to use JSch to ssh a Linux server with Windows Active Directory Authentication as PuTTY did

Tags: ssh, active-directory, kerberos, putty, jsch

We have a enterprise network with Windows Active Directory server and a Linux server in our network. We use Kerberos authentication in Linux server. And a PuTTY windows client with checked gssapi authentication from a PC in network can ssh our Linux server after user login with their AD account. The PuTTY client only has user name and don't ask user input password.

Now we want to use JSch library to develop a Java SSH program like PuTTY to access this Linux server. If we apply user AD user name/password into JSch session we can access the Linux. **But the question is How do we use JSch without asking user AD password as what PuTTY did**?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Ed

Answer (score 0):

It would help ih you share PuTTY event log.

Though I assume that PuTTY uses `SECUR32.DLL` for the authentication.

I do not think that JSch supports that. While it does support Kerberos for Windows for authentication, if enabled in JDK.